# Hotmodule autoreload chrome from vagrant-vm without ssh-tunnel

Tags: ubuntu, webpack, vagrant, virtualbox, hot-module-replacement

I have a Vagrant VM running in Oracle VM Virtualbox with a webpack installation.

The Hot-Module Autoreload Feature for the browser is working when I expose the Webpack-Node Server to `127.0.0.1:8080` and then ssh-tunnel into `ssh -L 8080:localhost:8080 vagrant@192.168.33.10`.
After that I can connect to the NodeServer with my browser via `localhost:8080`. When I expose it to `0.0.0.0:8080` I can reach the Server via `192.169.33.10:8080` without the ssh-tunnel but the browser won't autoreload on changes because they can't communicate anymore? When I now ssh-tunnel into the server the autoreload is working.

- I've added `config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8080, host:
  8080, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"` to the Vagrantfile which adds the first entry on the right side to the [Network-Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xQjF.png). That doesn't seem to make a difference since I am still required to have an active ssh-tunnel.
- I can curl the page from the guest-vm `curl -v 'http://localhost:8080'` which returns `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`
- What I get when I curl the page from the host-machine via `curl -v 'http://localhost:8080'` without a ssh-tunnel

```
 * Rebuilt URL to: http://localhost:8080/
 * timeout on name lookup is not supported
 *   Trying ::1...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
 * Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.49.1
> Accept: */*
>
 * Recv failure: Connection was aborted
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
 * Closing connection 0
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection was aborted
```

- When I curl from my host-machine with an active ssh-tunnel:

```
$ curl -v 'http://localhost:8080'
* Rebuilt URL to: http://localhost:8080/
* timeout on name lookup is not supported
*   Trying ::1...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.49.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< X-Powered-By: Express
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Content-Length: 974
< ETag: W/"3ce-MASXCzkp0dBO+UKSABDYEzPzueg"
< Date: Mon, 15 Apr 2019 13:21:35 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
<
{ [974 bytes data]
100   974  100   974    0     0  60875      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  951k<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

....
```

Since I don't know a lot about networking and these kind of things this question might seem stupid but is it even possible to have this feature working without an active ssh-tunnel?